# PHP version mismatching

Tags: php, apache, amazon-ec2

I started a Amazon EC2 instance using Elastic Beanstalk. It came with PHP 5.3 but I needed 5.2.
I downgraded the version and restarted apache. If I type "php -v" I see

```
PHP 5.2.17 (cli) (built: Oct 17 2013 16:24:38) 
Copyright (c) 1997-2010 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.2.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2010 Zend Technologies
```

But if I execute phphinfo() on the server it returns : PHP Version 5.3.27

The server is Apache httpd

Any help?

Comment: you are running 2 versions, one for the command line one for Apache\http.

Comment: uninstall both versions, reinstall what versions you want.

Comment: Check the config files AND environment variables.. cli runs most likely with system settings (environment)

Comment: That's what I tried to do: sudo yum uninstall php php-*

Comment: No luck so far. Any other clue?